# How to execute H2db generated statment in postgres

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, h2db

Below statmen generated from h2

```
 INSERT INTO EPSG_ALIAS
   (ALIAS_CODE, OBJECT_TABLE_NAME, OBJECT_CODE, NAMING_SYSTEM_CODE, ALIAS, REMARKS) 
 VALUES 
   (1431, 'Datum', 6123, 7300, STRINGDECODE('Kartastokoordinaattij\ufffdrjestelm\ufffd (1966)'), NULL);
```

When i execute the above statment in postgresql i am getting following error.

```
ERROR: function stringdecode(unknown) does not exist
SQL state: 42883
Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
Character: 140
```

Comment: What does stringdecode do, find an equivalent function in postgres and use that instead.

Comment: it will convert unicode string (\ufffd) to actual character(i.e. special character)

Comment: How is this regex related?

Comment: Have you investigated whether you could just `CREATE FUNCTION STRINGDECODE(text) ...` in PostgreSQL to mimic the behaviour of the corresponding H2 function?

Answer (score 2):

[STRINGDECODE](http://www.h2database.com/html/functions.html#stringdecode) is the way of H2 to read 'ASCII written UTF-8 characters'.

For Postgres, it's a simple 'E' before your string:

```
STRINGDECODE('Kartastokoordinaattij\ufffdrjestelm\ufffd (1966)')
```

Becomes

```
E'Kartastokoordinaattij\ufffdrjestelm\ufffd (1966)'
```